# How to access parameters passed to Component from AppControler in CakePHP 2.4

Tags: cakephp

I have created a component called `ApiComponent` to handle opening an HttpSocket to another server to post information. It looks like this:

```
class ApiComponent extends Component {

    public function connect($endpoint,$data) {
        App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
        $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();            
        // rest of the code
    }

}
```

This works in the sense that I can call `$this->Api->connect('/posts/add.json',$data);` from my controller and the code is executed as expected.

However, I have a lot of settings in the `$HttpSocket->request` such as the hostname, port number, username, password etc etc that I'd like to take out of the Component and put in a config file.

According to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#including-your-component-in-your-controllers I can pass parameters to the Component from the AppController like this:

```
public $components = array(
    'Api' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '80'
    ),
    'Session', 'Auth'
);
```

The manual says that this would pass the array to `ApiComponent::__construct()` but it doesn't say how I'm supposed to access the data in the component (or, it may... I'm in unfamiliar territory here).

So, my questions are:

1) Is it appropriate to put things like host, username, password etc in the AppController like this? And...

2) ...if so, how do I access them from within the Component?

...or...

3) ...if not, where exactly should I place settings like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, it's not appropriate (so it's unclear). Controllers are for system/business logic, not for configurations.
2. (and 3.) You can probably use the following methods to store configurations:

   1. Good, old constant way:

      It's easy, just `define(key, value)` these credentials in your `bootstrap.php` and you should be fine, and it's globally accessible.
   2. Use [`Configure`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#configure-class) class

      Configure is pretty handy as it's global to CakePHP. You simply do `Configure::write()` to write the credentials in your `bootstrap.php` file. Yes it will have some minor overheads if you don't mind, but should not be noticeable.

Comment: Thanks @Lionel Chan - that seems to be the best way of achieving what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

In your ApiComponent your settings are stored in:

```
$this->settings
```

see [API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Component.html#73-86)

I don't fully agree with @Lionel Chan: I don't think it's such a bad idea to store that values in the Component settings. But also using Configure class is a good practice.

Comment: Well, depends on what type of settings is that. If it's some secret key or public/private key, why store in the settings? Let's say next time another developer forked the project, if he wanted to use his own API keys, does he need to branch out the controller simply to have a different setting? Settings is good too, but for some generic settings would be good.